# Size of Memory Cache used in applications such as Instagram

Tags: architecture, memcached, system-design

I am learning system design concepts and have come across the concept of memcache or memory cache (like redis). For big applications such as Instagram or Tinder, where they have DAU over 10M. And stores data upto 500TB or more in relational databases. There can be many possible queries that are expensive if carried out for million of users on daily basis. To get rid of this issue, memcache is used to store some precomputed results that can be reverted immediately without querying on DB. Which improves the system performance considerably.

But I am not sure up to what size memcache is used for such big applications which have data stored in DB upto 500TB or even more.
Memcache upto **300GB(based on some rough calculations)** for such applications to store result of few queries for 40M users considering that these applications have total of over billion users active or inactive. Is it a good number to respond in a system design interview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

300GB of Memory Cache is a lot less as compared to the cache used in real-world applications with millions of users. Amazon ElastiCache for Redis is a blazing-fast, in-memory caching service that enables microsecond latency to power internet-scale, real-time applications. Developers can use ElastiCache for Redis as an in-memory nonrelational database for caching or use cases that don't require high data durability. The ElastiCache for Redis cluster configuration supports up to 15 shards and enables customers to run Redis workloads with up to **6.1 TB of in-memory capacity** in a single cluster. Refer - [https://aws.amazon.com/nosql/in-memory/#:~:text=Amazon%20ElastiCache%20for%20Redis%20is,capacity%20in%20a%20single%20cluster](https://aws.amazon.com/nosql/in-memory/#:%7E:text=Amazon%20ElastiCache%20for%20Redis%20is,capacity%20in%20a%20single%20cluster)
6.1TB is a lot more than 300GB as stated in the question.
So, yes we can respond memcache upto 300GB based on some rough calculations during system design interview.

Refer below links to see how memcache is calculated -

1. https://itsallbinary.com/system-design-back-of-envelop-calculations-for-storage-size-bandwidth-traffic-etc-estimates/
2. https://leetcode.com/discuss/interview-question/system-design/357656/experience-with-back-of-the-envelope-calculations